# Stop click event firing last thing that got appended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cs3xt67j/3/

It creates new divs with tabs on the click of the button. I have added an eventListener on each tab which is suppose to hide every div inside a container except the one that relates to that tab :

```
 function showThisDiv(selection){
  console.log(selection)
  var children = document.getElementById('mainContainerDiv').childNodes;
  for(i=0;i<children.length;i++){
  if(selection!=children[i].id){
    document.getElementById(selection).classList.add('hidden');
  }
    document.getElementById(selection).classList.remove('hidden');
  }

  console.log(children)
  //document.getElementById(selection).classList.remove('hidden');
  }
```

I added this event when i first create the divs (in the function that gets called from button click ) like so :

```
 newDivTab.addEventListener("click",function(){ return showThisDiv('containerDiv'+divCount)});
```

But every time the event fires, it calls the last selection that got added to event rather than the thing that got added when i created the divs. Probably easier if you see the console log from the fiddle. Just create a few tabs by clicking the button and click the tabs created then see console logs

Comment: why not changing the shoThisDiv function to read the count attribute and get the name of div to show, by itself (or store the whole name as attr)

Comment: You don't even need the variable. You're using the count in the `id`, so you could just grab it from that `id`. So then you could just do `newDivTab.addEventListener("click", showThisDiv);` and then within `showThisDiv`, use `this.id` and strip way the `"tab"` at the end. Like this `this.id.slice(-3)`.

Comment: ...also, using `.setAttribute()` is longer and more clunky for most purposes. Simply use `newDiv.id = 'containerDiv' + divCount;
  newDiv.className = 'containerDiv';`

Comment: That should have been `.slice(0, -3)` above.

Comment: @squint thank you very much :)) Very good points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/cs3xt67j/4/)

Basically you need to duplicate value of `divCount` and store it into other context to preserve it's value.

So, instead of:

```
newDivTab.addEventListener("click",function(){ return showThisDiv('containerDiv'+divCount)});
```

Use:

```
var localCount = divCount;
newDivTab.addEventListener("click",function(){ return showThisDiv('containerDiv'+localCount)});
```

Comment: great find. Thankyou. I think someone downvoted due to you posting code. But I know how it is when you just want to get the answer across asap. I will select as answer when I can :))

Answer (score 1):

Every time a div is clicked it calls the function

```
function(){ return showThisDiv('containerDiv'+divCount)}
```

so the concatenation of the string `'containerDiv'+divCount` doesn't get evaluated until the click, so it is using whatever the current value of `divCount` is, so the possible div.

These are called closures and a lot smart people have written about them: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

To fix wat you're doing i would suggest wrapping the onclick function in another function and pass it the wanted id

```
newDivTab.addEventListener("click",(function(divID){ 
    return function(){
      showThisDiv('containerDiv'+divID)
    }
})(divCount))
```

To quote the link above (with i being equivalent to your divCount):

> Calling this function creates a new variable scope for each iteration because variable scope is created at execution time. This allows me to pass on the value of i to this new scope.